# Load Content on Dropdown Select

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

This code does not currently work. I am using wordpress and trying to display content according to the drop down selected. To be more specific, the content is a different loop based on the taxonomy.

```
<form method="post" action="">
<select name="only_criteria" onchange="submit();">
        <option selected="selected">Please Choose</option>
        <option value="one">One</option>
        <option value="two">Two</option>
        <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>
</form>

<div class="archive-wrap">
 <div class="carousel">
<?php 
 if(isset($_POST['only_criteria']) && $_POST['only_criteria'] == '')  {   
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'my_custom_post_type',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'my_taxonomy',
                'terms'    => array( 'tax_one','tax_two','tax_three'),
      ),
    ),
  ) );
  } else if(isset($_POST['only_criteria']) && $_POST['only_criteria'] == 'one')  {   
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'my_custom_post_type',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'my_taxonomy',
                'terms'    => array( 'tax_one'),
      ),
    ),
  ) );
  } else if(isset($_POST['only_criteria']) && $_POST['only_criteria'] == 'two')  {   
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'my_custom_post_type',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'my_taxonomy',
                'terms'    => array( 'tax_two'),
      ),
    ),
  ) );
  } else if(isset($_POST['only_criteria']) && $_POST['only_criteria'] == 'three')  {   
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'my_custom_post_type',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'my_taxonomy',
                'terms'    => array('tax_three'),
      ),
    ),
  ) );
  }
?>
```

I have done similar things with tabs by putting each loop in a tab. I am trying to build it this way because I was hoping it would reduce load times in the long run and be more efficient

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Why are you saying that it is currently not working? Please describe the problem a little bit more.

Comment: When I select a drop down it automatically submits. The page refreshes, the domain remains the same but it says page not found. There are no errors in the console. If I remove the first if statement the first loop will show, but not with the if statement in place.

Comment: No cache plugins.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to giving us more info as to why it doesn't work, here are a couple of suggestions.

First, you can condense the last 3 loop settings to one by using a variable in your terms parameter:

Set "terms" => $temp;
The terms parameter does not have to be an array.
Use this logic to set $temp:

```
switch ($_post['only_criteria']) {
case "one"
  $temp = 'tax_one';
case "two"
  $temp = 'tax_two';
case "three"
  $temp = 'tax_three';
}

Second, I believe you have to use admin-post logic to handle a form in wp. 
You also don't this, since you only have one array: 
'relation' => 'AND',
```

Comment: Thank you. When I select a drop down it automatically submits which is what I want. The page refreshes, the domain remains the same but it says page not found. There are no errors in the console. If I remove the first if statement the first loop will show, but not with the if statement in place. I started reading about admin post logic but I will have to do some more.